# nginx proxy_pass with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I can't seem to make this nginx config work. I have a rails app, and I need to proxy everything under a path to a Java/Tomcat setup. I have another route (which does hit the main rails app) under lockdown and that works, but the `proxy_pass` doesn't; it just hits the main app.

- It seems that when I remove the `lockdown` location directive, it works.
- Reordering the two `location` directives has no effect.

The basic config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /rails/app/public;
  rails_env development;
  passenger_enabled on;

  location /JavaApp {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaApp/;
  }

  location /lockdown {
    # Have to re-enable passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I had tried every combination, but I went through a bunch more and found that this worked:

```
location ~ \.jsp$
```

Which boggled my mind because before it whined about not allowing regex in the location with proxy_pass, but I had a path in the proxy pass line... SO!

This does the trick

```
location ~ /JavaApp {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing passenger_enabled pn; from the top level of the server {} block and I think it will start working for you.

Comment: That just makes the whole thing (except for the /lockdown) not work :( I get a 404 on /JavaApp. I also tried removing passenger_enabled from the top level and adding another "location /" block and setting passenger enabled in there, but no dice.